# PHP check if a string contains a specific character

Tags: php

I have 2 strings `$verify` and `$test`.  I want to check if `$test` contains elements from `$verify` at specific points. `$test[4] = e` and `$test[9] = ]`. How can I check if `e` and `]` in `$verify`?

```
$verify = "aes7]";
$test = "09ske-2?;]3fs{";

if ($test[4] == $verify AND $test[9] == $verify) {
    echo "Match";
} else {
    echo "No Match";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `strpos()` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

https://paiza.io/projects/n10TMV4Ate8-vtzioDrsMg

```
<?php

$verify = "aes7]";
$test = "09ske-2?;]3fs{";

if (strpos($verify, $test[4]) !== false && strpos($verify, $test[9]) !== false) {
    echo "Match";
} else {
    echo "No Match";
}
?>
```

Comment: Normally would use  `! == false` instead of `> -1`

Answer (score 3):

As of PHP8 you can use [str_contains()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php)

```
<?php

$verify = "aes7]";
$test = "09ske-2?;]3fs{";

if (str_contains($verify, $test[4]) && str_contains($verify, $test[9])) {
    echo "Match";
} else {
    echo "No Match";
}
?>
```

<sup>Thanks to @symlink for the code snippet I butchered</sup>